# Can I start up terminal, make it open the python interactive shell and run a few python statements with the same command in os x?

Tags: python, macos, shell, terminal

I often do this to prepare for some django debugging:

- Open up a terminal window in os x (10.6)
- start the python interpreter
- run these commands in python:

  from django.core.management import setup_environ
  import settings
  setup_environ(settings)

Is it possible to automate these actions and make a shortcut that I can doubleclick to invoke?

Answer (score 2):

If you use django you should consider running the command `python manage.py shell` to debug django applications.

Even better, try the `shell_plus` command from the excellent [django command extension](http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/) add-on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`PYTHONSTARTUP`](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP) environment variable to your advantage here if you want to throw that in a script and then have a batch file load up a shell with that environment variable.